# Nestjs- Got 'undefined' as output while fetching data from mongodb in json format

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, nestjs

I am trying to fetch name and price property of a collection from MongoDB and I got output like this.

[image]

When I fetched name property then it shows correct value, but when I fetched price property then I got undefined value.

Note: i don't want to fetch all the properties which available on total. i just want to fetch price property of an object which is on first index of an array

Here is the code of service-:

```
async total(){
    const total= await this.usersmodel.find().exec()
    try{
        //return total[0].name
        console.log(total[0].name)
        console.log(total[0].price)
    }
    catch(error){
        return error.message
    }
}
```

Here is the code of controller-:

```
@Post('total')
async total(){
    return this.usersService.total();
}
}
```

Comment: `return await this.usersService.total();`?

Comment: Nope, not that. What does `console.log(total)` show you?

Comment: if i use console.log(total) then i get all the objects of array, but i want to fetch only price from object which is present on 0 index of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning any data from the service. You need to return what you fetched from Mongo.

```
async total(){
    const total= await this.usersmodel.find().exec()
    return total;
}
```

or

```
async total(){
    return await this.usersmodel.find().exec()
}
```

If you want to select only one field like price, use `.select("price")`. Or `.select("name price")` if you want more than one.

Also add `.lean()` to get raw data and not some Mongoose weirdo. Currently you're not getting JSON, but an array of Mongoose weirdos. By weirdo I mean stupid Mongoose objects, often immutable, with hidden keys and methods, that look like simple JSON but are *absolutely not*. `.lean()` will give you simple JSON. And it's faster.

`usersmodel.find().select("price").lean().exec()`

Comment: If i used your method then i'll get all the properties of document but i want only specific property that is price and nothing else.  in screenshot i just trying to tell you my issue us that if i fetch name then it works properly but when am trying to fetch price its shows undefined